# How do I specify which function I want to get parameters from?

Tags: vb.net

I have to learn visual basic for my job and I've been writing code on my own time to help speed up the process. I have a basic console application here, and I think I'm passing parameters incorrectly.

What this program is supposed to do is draw a bunch of ASCII letters in a rectangle. One of those letters will represent the player. When the player presses a key it should clear the screen and redraw the whole thing with the player in his new position based on which arrow key is pressed.

The problem is that I split all the code into subs and functions to make it easier to maintain and to understand. Now it is broken, and when a key is pressed the player's position no longer changes.

```
   Sub Game()
        Dim width As Integer = 60
        Dim height As Integer = 10
        Dim playerX As Integer = 5
        Dim playerY As Integer = 5
        Dim cursorX As Integer = 0
        Dim cursorY As Integer = 0
        Dim numofTiles As Integer = 0
        Dim keyPressed As ConsoleKeyInfo = Nothing

    While True
        numofTiles = 0
        cursorY = 0
        'Each time the screen is updated these variables need to go back to default
        For i = 0 To height - 1
            cursorY += 1
            cursorX = 0
            'we are starting on a new line so the X position of the cursor will go back to 0
            For j = 0 To width - 1
                DrawTiles(cursorX, playerX, cursorY, playerY)
                cursorX += 1
                numofTiles += 1
                'update information since we just drew a char to the screen
            Next
            Console.WriteLine()
        Next
        keyPressed = Console.ReadKey()
        If PlayerPressedLeftKey(keyPressed) Then
            If LeftIsClear(playerX) Then
                MovePlayerLeft(playerX)
            End If
        ElseIf PlayerPressedRightKey(keyPressed) Then
            If RightIsClear(playerX, width) Then
                MovePlayerRight(playerX)
            End If
        ElseIf PlayerPressedUpKey(keyPressed) Then
            If TopIsClear(playerY) Then
                MovePlayerUp(playerY)
            End If
        ElseIf PlayerPressedDownKey(keyPressed) Then
            If BottomIsClear(playerY, height) Then
                MovePlayerDown(playerY)
            End If
        End If
        Console.Clear()
    End While
End Sub
Sub DrawTiles(cursorX, playerX, cursorY, playerY)
    If Not CursorIsOnPlayersPosition(cursorX, playerX, cursorY, playerY) Then
        DrawBackgroundTile()
    ElseIf CursorIsOnPlayersPosition(cursorX, playerX, cursorY, playerY) Then
        DrawPlayer()
    End If
End Sub
Function RightIsClear(playerX, width)
    If playerX + 1 < width Then : Return True
    Else : Return False
    End If
End Function
Function LeftIsClear(playerX)
    If playerX > 0 Then : Return True
    Else : Return False
    End If

End Function
Function BottomIsClear(playerY, height)
    If playerY < height Then : Return True
    Else : Return False
    End If
End Function
Function TopIsClear(playerY)
    If playerY - 1 > 0 Then : Return True
        'top edge of screen is (X, 0)
    Else : Return False
    End If

End Function
Function CursorIsOnPlayersPosition(cursorX, playerX, cursorY, playerY)
    If cursorX = playerX AndAlso cursorY = playerY Then
        Return True
    Else : Return False
    End If
End Function
Sub DrawPlayer()
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green
    Console.Write("X")
    Console.ResetColor()
End Sub
Sub DrawBackgroundTile()
    Console.Write("-")
End Sub
Function PlayerPressedLeftKey(keyPressed)
    If keyPressed.Key = ConsoleKey.LeftArrow Then
        Return True
    Else : Return False
    End If
End Function
Function PlayerPressedRightKey(keyPressed)
    If keyPressed.Key = ConsoleKey.RightArrow Then
        Return True
    Else : Return False
    End If
End Function
Function PlayerPressedUpKey(keyPressed)
    If keyPressed.Key = ConsoleKey.UpArrow Then
        Return True
    Else : Return False
    End If
End Function
Function PlayerPressedDownKey(keyPressed)
    If keyPressed.Key = ConsoleKey.DownArrow Then
        Return True
    Else : Return False
    End If
End Function
Sub MovePlayerLeft(playerX)
    playerX -= 1
End Sub
Sub MovePlayerRight(playerX)
    playerX += 1
End Sub
Sub MovePlayerUp(playerY)
    playerY -= 1
End Sub
Sub MovePlayerDown(playerY)
    playerY += 1
End Sub
```

I'm pretty sure the LeftIsClear(),RightIsClear(),etc functions are the problem.

```
If LeftIsClear(playerX) Then
    MovePlayerLeft(playerX)
        End If
```

Both the LeftIsClear() function and the MovePlayerLeft() sub take playerX as a parameter, and MovePlayerLeft() is inside LeftIsClear(). I'm sure this is breaking the code so that I can no longer change the player's position.

I know this is a big chunk of code but I wanted to try to be as clear as possible about my problem. The important parts are the while True loop and the parameters that the functions take.

Comment: Before doing *anything* else, change the **[option strict compiler option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/c553zwz0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)** from `off` to `on`. Once fixed and if the problem persists, edit your question. Replace the old code with the new code.

Comment: I changed it to strict but I got ~70 errors that Im having to go through and fix one by one. Some of the old lines of code could be fixed by the IDE but others caused errors that I don't know how to fix, like "Option Strict On Disallows Late Binding".

Comment: This is very easy to fix. You need to tell the compile what type of data you're using. Take this function for instance: `Function PlayerPressedLeftKey(keyPressed)`. What is the type of `keyPressed`? As is its `Object` and the object type doesn't have a property named `Key`. I guess the correct type is `ConsoleKeyInfo`. And what type of data do the function return? I guess `Boolean`. The correct signature should look like this: `Function PlayerPressedUpKey(keyPressed As ConsoleKeyInfo) As Boolean`

Comment: Putting "As Boolean" at the end of the function declaration seems to fix the problem. Thanks